# Storing large volume of text in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Name (Int), Id (Int), Description (VARCHAR)
```

The problem I have is Description is likely to be a paragraph of text (over 100 characters).

My Questionsl

1) Is VARCHAR a suitable datatype to store this type of data?

2) Is MySQL an ideal storage solution for this data, or should I look at writing to files instead?

N.B. I won't be querying the Description, just storing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL (as of version 5.7) supports up to 65,535 bytes in a `varchar` column. Note that the length of a row (the combined maximum sizes of all columns) is also 65,535 bytes. Because it uses UTF-8 the number of characters stored might be less than this limit (as UTF-8 uses a varying number of bytes per character).

Note that in databases, a 100-character storage requirement isn't really significant. Database systems like these can store many kilobytes in a single row, and even larger data (single values sized in the gigabytes and over) can be stored in blob columns (`BLOB`, `TEXT`).

If you won't be querying the data and if the data length might excess 65KiB then you should use the `TEXT` data-type instead, which stores large-sized values in a different physical storage location which makes data-lookup somewhat more expensive, and hinders indexing.